# Need jenkins plugin to support both serial and parallel triggering

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a deployment script configured in Jenkins

If a Person A triggered a deployment of Build1 in QA environment already, It should not allow the Person B to trigger the same build in same Environment.

But the Build1 Deployment can be triggered in other environment such as Stage.

Build1, Build2 Can be triggered parallely in same environment -> Here Parallel triggering is allowed
Build1 Cannot be triggered parallely in same environment -> Here Parallel triggering is not allowed.

Please not this job is purely with shell script and a single job supports multiple environments.

Any one can help me in finding some jenkin plugin or the way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin)

1. Install it.
2. In your **Build1** job set *"Maximum Concurrent Builds Per Node"* to **1**.
3. Configure two Jenkins slaves, one for QE env and another is for Stage env, both with at least **two** executors.
4. Don't forget to enable concurrent builds in your jobs where needed (there is a separate checkbox for this).

After that **Build1** job will not be scheduled on the same node even if there are free executors. At the same time other jobs will be able to utilize them freely.

Comment: Thanks izzekil, I had already gone through about this Throttle plugin, but was not convinced fully with this.. With this approach if I have 'n' environments then I should have 'n' slaves is it?

Comment: Yes, it is so. For me this seems to be a natural approach for your needs as the slaves are distinguishable but not the executors within a slave.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, let me try it out.. 
Another one thing , Is there a way to get the console out put of last 10 jobs triggerd in jenkins through command line? Currently I am using curl command for last build triggered like below
curl --user 'username:password' "https://URL/jobname/lastBuild/?"

Is there any such commands for last 'n' jobs triggered?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to get it with a single request. However you can use Jenkins REST API to get the numbers of last N build i.e. as a JSON: `URL/job/api/json?tree=builds[number]{0,10}&pretty=true` (or similar with XML+xpath). Then parse it for numbers and access `URL/jobname/NUMBER/consoleText`. [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) is inaccessible for me at the moment so there is a brief article from Cloudbees: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/taming-jenkins-json-api-depth-and-tree